# data import and calculation in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, data-science

I'm working with a data set of around 50 Gb so i decided to work by "pieces" calling and eliminating each data set after each calculation has been performed. I have 8 different .mat files, each one containing a cell{1,5} that contains each an array of (1,50) and finally a 2d array of (1024,1024). My question is, can i change somehow the name of the array containing this data inside the calculation loop? Code is below.

```
ld = [5,10,15,20,25,50,75,100];

for i=1:8

    load(sprintf('U%i.mat',ld(i)));

    for a = 1:1024
        for b = 1:1024
            for c = 1:50
                stad_pmmh(c) = 'U_%i{c}(a,b);   %%%%Here is the main issue and where i need a "dynamical naming"
            end
            STAD_pmmh{a,b} = stad_pmmh;
            dev_pmmh(a,b) = std(STAD_pmmh{a,b});
        end
    end

    save(sprintf('dev_%i',ld(i)),'dev_pmmh');
%     
    clear (sprintf('U_%i',ld(i)));
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load your .mat content into a structure, asking for an output argument when you load the data. And then use the dynamic field naming to access your data.

To load data from a .mat file into a structure, use

```
data = load('filename');
```

Every variable in the .mat will become a field in Structure. In your case,

```
data = load('U5');
data.U5
```

And then you can access structure fields via dynamic naming :

```
my_field = 'U5';
data.(my_field)
```

In your case :

```
file_name = sprintf('U%i',ld(i))
data = load(file_name); % You don't need the .mat extension to load a .mat file
[...]
stad_pmmh(c) = data.(file_name){c}(a,b);
```

Reference in Matlab Help:

[load: Load variables from file into workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#btm0etn-1-S)

[Generate Field Names from Variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)